# AWS EC2 - SQL server with multiple writers

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a requirement where I need to see the possibility of having multiple read and write clusters for SQL Server deployed in Amazon EC2.
I understand that we can configure Always on High Availablity for SQL Servers which does support multiple read replicas.

My questions is, Is it possible to have multiple write replicas for a single database running in EC2?
We have multiple batch jobs running on single database and there are lot of load on this database, effecting the performance of application.

I am quite new to AWS and any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Regards,
Madhu

Comment: Why do you use a database in EC2, why not use RDS with Microsoft SQL Server?!

Comment: There are service brokers used in SQL Server. RDS has limited functionality when it comes to service brokers in SQL Server. So we cannot opt for RDS.